# Retrieving fields in php (codeigniter) from mysql stored as a bit data-type

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in MySQL of which one of the column is of bit-type, let's call it 'flag' . I am developing in PHP with codeigniter as the framework. I am not quite sure, how I could retrieve this bit field 'flag' in my controller. 
'query' is the array that fetches the data from the model 'm_project_info'.

```
$query['info'] = $this->m_project_info->project_info($id);
foreach ($query['info'] as $row)
            if ($row->flag == 0)
                     ....;
```

So I know for sure `$row->flag`, isn't the right way. Any idea what it should be instead?

Strange enough, this works fine while on Windows platform, however fails in Redhat. But that would be a different question altogether.

Comment: I think $row['flag']............

Comment: can you post te database query ??

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` the `$query['info']` and check the result . then you willable to decide what to do

if it is an boject

```
$query['info'][0]->flag
```

if it is an array

```
$query['info'][0]['flag']
```